# NW js Use Native Node Modules Commands on Windows Not Working

Tags: javascript, powershell, command, export

How can I run the 'export' command in Windows Powershell?

As mentioned on
http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/For%20Users/Advanced/Use%20Native%20Node%20Modules/

i've done the part for non-LTS Releases:

```
npm install -g nw-gyp
```

-> this works

B U T the next command doesn't:

```
export npm_config_target=0.18.5
```

The command "export" is not found:

> Die Benennung "export" wurde nicht als Name eines Cmdlet, einer Funktion, einer Skriptdatei oder eines ausführbaren Programms erkannt. Überprüfen Sie die Schreibweise des Namens, oder ob der Pfad korrekt ist (sofern enthalten), und wieder
>   holen Sie den Vorgang.
>   Bei Zeile:1 Zeichen:7
>   + export <<<<  npm_config_target=0.18.5
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (export:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

At the end, I only want to use other node modules in NW js. For this, the steps as described are necessary.

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: Export isn't a windows command. To store an environment variable in the current cmd instance use `set`, to store permanently use `setx.exe`

Answer (score 0):

Ok. As I see, I was working too long today. So I didn't see the special windows commands in the list.

The answer is like LotPins mentioned above:

**set npm_config_target=0.18.5**

*instead of*

**export npm_config_target=0.18.5**

Sorry for the mistake.